# compilation error with apache giraph (building from the trunk)

Tags: apache, build, giraph

```
===================Below is the error============================

[INFO] Building jar:
/home/rob/dev/apache/giraph-trunk/giraph/giraph-core/target/giraph-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT-for-hadoop-0.20.203.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar


[INFO] Total time: 1:12.383s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 20 17:25:46 PST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/119M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project giraph-examples: Could not
resolve dependencies for project
org.apache.giraph:giraph-examples:jar:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find
org.apache.giraph:giraph-core:jar:tests:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT in
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository,
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I have hadoop installed on my machine but I am unable to build it.
thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you compile only the example project. You have to import parent project, core project and example project. Then to compile Giraph trunk for pure Yarn you can use:

```
clean package -P hadoop_yarn -Dhadoop.version=2.2.0 -DskipTests
```

BTW. what is your java version, maven version?